# Solution of Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{r/\beta}e^{-\alpha x}}{\left(1-(1-\beta)e^{-x}\right)^{\alpha+1}} \, dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function

I need to solve the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{r/\beta}e^{-\alpha x}}{\left(1-(1-\beta)e^{-x}\right)^{\alpha+1}} \, dx$$

where $r,\alpha,\beta>0$.

kindly help me to solve this integral.

Answer (score 1):

As 
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^s}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{s+j-1\choose j}x^j        ----(1)$$
for $|x|<1$ (reference is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)). Since $e^{-x}$ lies between 0 and 1 for interval $(0,\infty)$. So we have two cases for $0<\beta<2$ and $\beta>2$.

For $0<\beta<2$, using above result we can write
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\alpha+j\choose j}(1-\beta)^j\int_0^\infty x^{r/\beta} e^{-x(\alpha +j)}dx$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\alpha+j\choose j}\frac{(1-\beta)^j}{(\alpha+j)^{r/\beta+1}}\int_0^\infty x^{r/\beta} e^{-x}dx$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\alpha+j\choose j}\frac{(1-\beta)^j}{(\alpha+j)^{r/\beta+1}}\Gamma \left( r/\beta +1 \right)$$

and now for $\beta>2$, rewriting the integral as

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{r/\beta} e^{-\alpha x}}{\beta(1-(e^{-x}-1)\frac{(\beta-1)}{\beta})^{\alpha+1}}dx$$
using (1) we can write
$$\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\alpha+j\choose j}(\frac{\beta-1}{\beta})^{j}\int_0^\infty x^{r/\beta} e^{-\alpha x}(e^{-x}-1)^{j} dx$$

$$\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\alpha+j\choose j}(\frac{\beta-1}{\beta})^{j}\sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^{j+k}\int_0^\infty x^{r/\beta} e^{-(\alpha+k) x} dx$$ 
$$\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\alpha+j\choose j}(\frac{\beta-1}{\beta})^{j}\sum_{k=0}^j \frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{(\alpha+k)^{r/\beta +1}}\Gamma \left( r/\beta +1 \right)$$

hence proved.

Comment: This is not a closed-form expression: see [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

Comment: @user64494 But at least she gives the expressable series form, don't you know that the integral is more complicated than [Lerch zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Integral_representations)?

Comment: @SAAN Thanks for you great trial. But isn't the first approach in fact suitable for $|1-\beta|<1$ , i.e. $0<\beta<2$ , and the second approach in fact suitable for $|1-\beta|>1$ , i.e. $\beta>2$ ?

Comment: @HarryPeter Thanks to point out my mistake, I edit the answer. Also kindly change "She" with "He" in your first comment because my gender is male:@.